# Umbraco 7.3 Identity Issues

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a member login built using UmbracoIdentity. (https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity)

The UserManager in the below code is returned as null. I have included the property that gets the UserManager.

Why would this be null? Is this something to do with the UmbracoIdentity package or is it due to upgrades to 7.3 that break identity? I have read some rumblings about changes in 7.3 that could cause this but nothing specific enough for me to be sure.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> HandleLogin([Bind(Prefix = "loginModel")] LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // UserManager is null here - WHY!?
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, true);
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("loginModel", "Invalid username or password");
    }

    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}

public UmbracoMembersUserManager<UmbracoApplicationMember> UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? (_userManager = OwinContext
            .GetUserManager<UmbracoMembersUserManager<UmbracoApplicationMember>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming this works like the normal Identity framework, have you added the UserManager to the OwinContext in your application startup?

Comment: Yes but it wasn't being hit, thanks for the brain jolt, David.

Answer (score 0):

My `UmbracoIdentityStartup` was not being executed.

I had this line in my web.config:

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" />
```

Commenting this line out fixes the issue.

I had not added this line so assumed it was something to do with the package, however examining the package further suggested otherwise.